# Install Customer.io Tracking Script in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I am trying to install Customer.io to Yii but not sure the process so asking if anyone knows, how should I use the JavaScript code from http://customer.io/docs/api/javascript.html?

I tried to copy into my *footer.php* under views for main module but it gives me errors.

Comment: Javascript is not java!

Comment: You already have the code snippet, just put it in the main.php in your layouts folder.

Comment: Doesnt work :( cannot add to the code a java script file since the file is all PHP any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to include JS tracking code in all pages of your site, is to insert it into the master layout.

Browse to *protected/views/layouts/main.php*, and insert the JS at the bottom of your page right before the closing `<body>` tag like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var _cio = _cio || [];

      (function() {
        var a,b,c;a=function(f){return function(){_cio.push([f].
        concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}};b=["identify",
        "track"];for(c=0;c<b.length;c++){_cio[b[c]]=a(b[c])};
        var t = document.createElement('script'),
            s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        t.async = true;
        t.id    = 'cio-tracker';
        t.setAttribute('data-site-id', 'YOUR SITE ID HERE');
        t.src = 'https://assets.customer.io/assets/track.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s);
      })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```